# Python numpy random numbers probability

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, random

```
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mtptlb

print (np.__version__)
1.12.1
print (mtptlb.__version__)
2.0.2

%matplotlib inline
a=np.random.uniform(1,100,1000000)
b=range(1,101)
plt.hist(a)
```

[image]

Why does the Y axis show **100000**? 
np.random.uniform(1,100,**1000000**) has the value 1000000, so shouldn't it show 1000000 on y axis?

Answer (score 7):

By default [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) uses 10 bins. So all your 1 million values are distributed into 10 bins. For a perfect uniform distribution you would expect that you have 100k occurrences (1 million divided by 10) in each bin.

You can change the number of bins, i.e.

```
a=np.random.uniform(1, 100, 1000000)
plt.hist(a, bins=100)
```

[image]

Here it's divided into 100 bins and because it's a uniform distribution all bins are roughly at 10000.

Or just one bin if you want a count of 1 000 000:

```
a=np.random.uniform(1, 100, 1000000)
plt.hist(a, bins=1)
```

[image]